# how to detect end of audio file using jquery and html5

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I've got this jquery code and html to work OK for an English language training site.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css({"color": "purple", "font-weight" : "bolder"});
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css({"color": "black", "font-weight" : ""});
    }
  ); 
  $("p").click(function (event) {
    var element = $(this);
    var elementID = event.target.id;
    var oggVar = (elementID +".ogg");   
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', oggVar); 
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() { 
        audioElement.play(); 
    }, true);
    audioElement.play();    
  }); 
});

<div>
  <p id="one"> this is the first paragraph</p>
....   
  <p id="four"> this is the fourth paragraph</p> 
....   
</div>
```

the problem is that if text is clicked on while an audio file is playing (or double clicked) then the second file (or the same file) starts playing. So I end up with two files playing simultaneously. I need to prevent this. I think that the 'ended' event is relevant but, despite looking some examples, I can't see quite how to detect if a file is playing and wait until it's finished before allowing a second file to start (or even prevent it from playing at all). Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add event listeners for the [ended and playing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents) events. Also, why creating a audio tag via javascript? I would just create an empty hidden audio tag:

```
<audio id='myAudio' autoplay='autoplay'></audio>
```

You have two options:

- disable/enable the button/link when audio is playing/stopped (preferred imho)
- ignore clicks when already playing

Then add two eventlisteners to it:

```
var playing = false;

$('#myAudio').on('playing', function() {
   playing = true;
   // disable button/link
});
$('#myAudio').on('ended', function() {
   playing = false;
   // enable button/link
});

$("p").click(function (event) {
   if(!playing) {
      var element = $(this);
      var elementID = event.target.id;
      var oggVar = (elementID +".ogg");   
      var audioElement = $('#myAudio')[0];
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', oggVar); 
      audioElement.play();
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm sorry I wasn't able to get this to work. In the section - // load new source - are you suggesting reuse of the existing code within $("p").click(function (event),,, });   etc ?

Comment: In your click function, you set the new source and play it. I adapted the answer a bit.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in replying. I tried the most recent code you posted but to no avail. No audio on clicking. This is puzzling. I tried looking at it in firebug, putting a breakpoint at var playing, firebug steps thru to the next line - $('#myAudio').on('playing', function() but then drops into jquery.js. Any comments

Comment: Weird. Try to add an alert in the scope of your playing function. Other option is set playing to true after audioElement.play()

Comment: Still no joy. I placed alert(playing); within the click function body (before and within the if statement), no effect. I placed it immediately after var playing=false; false displayed on screen (not surprisingly). Also, when I put the alert just before the click function, no effect. And your last suggestion setting var playing=true after audionElement.play() - no effect. This is curious, to say the least.

Comment: You are sure your audio tag is correct? Does your mp3 file starts playing? Try $('#myAudio')[0].play() in the Chrome console.

Comment: I did a cut/paste on the audio tag and placed it first in <body></body> before the div tag containing the <p> section. The mp3.file does not start playing. I'm not sure what you mean by "Try $('#myAudio')[0]..." The mp3 files are valid, they play in a player OK.

Comment: thanks for your help, it's pointed me, more or less, in the right direction

Comment: I found I needed the `pause` event to detect when the user has stopped (= paused) the player.  This is also triggered when the track ends, so `ended` can even be removed. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaevents

Answer (score 1):

```
var myAudio = new Audio('someSound.ogg'); 
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
myAudio.play();
```

This worked for jquery audio.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ***var audioElement = null;***     

 $("p").click(function (event) {

    ***if (audioElement) {
        audioElement.pause();
     }***

var element = $(this);
var elementID = event.target.id;
var oggVar = (elementID +".ogg");   
audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', oggVar); 
audioElement.load();
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() { 
    audioElement.play(); 
}, true);
audioElement.play();    

 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help but this doesn't seem work. I'm not sure why. You did mean to insert - var audioElement = null; - and - if (audioElement) {audioElement.pause(); } - where indicated into the existing code?