# Play and pause buttons are working... but how do I reset button to show the play symbol once audio is over?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, audio

I've coded a button to display the "play" symbol (triangle). When you click the button, the selected audio plays and the button displays a "pause" symbol instead. If you click pause, the audio pauses and the button switches back to the play symbol. So far, so good. When the audio is OVER, however, the button keeps displaying the "pause" symbol. The audio resets, but the image does not; you can press the button again and the audio will play as many times as you like, but the image does not reset to the play triangle. Any advice for a newbie?

```
<div class="playFeatured">
<audio id="playA" preload='none'></audio>
<i><button id="pButtonA" class="featuredAudio fa fa-play" onclick="playAudioA()"></button></i>
</div>


<script>
var loopA = document.getElementById('playA');

function playAudioA() {
    if (loopA.paused) {
        loopA.play();
        pButtonA.className = "";
        pButtonA.className = "fa fa-pause";
    } else { 
        loopA.pause();
        pButtonA.className = "";
        pButtonA.className = "fa fa-play";
        loopA.currentTime = 0
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: show me the element #playA

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño, I added the code above. Thanks for looking!

Comment: check [how to detect end of audio file using jquery and html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586209/how-to-detect-end-of-audio-file-using-jquery-and-html5) instead of jQuery you can use addEventListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an oncomplete event for HTML5 audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092266/is-there-an-oncomplete-event-for-html5-audio)

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/SirXplosiv/pen/ZoBRea?editors=1010)

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño, thanks for setting that up! I'm seeing the same problem in the CodePen — the audio is resetting properly, but the button is not. Maybe it's a browser issue... are you seeing it reset?

Comment: Thanks, @Marquizzo and jcubic, for your suggestion of addEventListener. I got it working with that.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer, thanks to the suggestions offered above...

```
<script>
var loopA = document.getElementById('playA');

function playAudioA() {
    if (loopA.paused) {
        loopA.play();
        pButtonA.className = "";
        pButtonA.className = "fa fa-pause";
    } else { 
        loopA.pause();
        pButtonA.className = "";
        pButtonA.className = "fa fa-play";
        loopA.currentTime = 0
    } 
}
loopA.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    // Audio has ended when this function is executed.
        pButtonA.className = "";
        pButtonA.className = "fa fa-play";
},false);
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you put the `addEventListener()` lines OUTSIDE the function `playAudioA()`. The way you have it now, you're adding new event listeners every time you click the button, which can lead to unwanted behavior.